# How to stream video using WebRTC?

Tags: java, html, webrtc, jmf

I have gone through tutorials which allow video conferencing between peers by transmitting webcam and mic streams.  Is it possible to stream local video files from one PC to another using webRTC ?

I have implemented the same using RTP in JMF. Is webRTC the only alternative, or are there any other better alternatives for this task ?

Answer (score 1):

"`captureStreamUntilEnded`" allows us capture "`MediaStream`" from a `<video>` element; however, remeber, these API are (AFAIK) **not fully implemented** by any single vendor.

Firefox implemented prefixed version of "[`mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded`](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/experimental/mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded/)" however their RTCPeerConnection implementation is unable to add/understand stream coming from (i.e. generated by) [`mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded`](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/experimental/mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded/) because (AFAIK) [currently] "only one" media source i.e. "APM" is permitted both on chrome and firefox.

I tried to stream [pre-recorded medias using MediaSource API](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pre-recorded-Media-Streaming/) too; however, it is "not" realtime. Though, you can share chunks generated by MediaSource API as fast as possible using WebRTC SCTP based data channels; however, MediaSource API has itself limited support.

**MediaSource API** are useful to play chunks (in a `<video>` element) instead of waiting for the whole file to be streamed or downloaded.